# Async Methods overwriting previous call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, discord

I am writing a console application wherein I'm using async calls to another method.  I have the same call happening twice with different overloads.  When I'm debugging I can see that the first call got the correct information but when the second call finishes the first call variable is overwritten with the second call's results.

Its literally 2 lines of code that are giving me issues.

```
var myParty = await _partyService.GetParty(Context.User.Id);
var compParty = await _partyService.GetParty(0);
```

myParty will initially have the correct values, but when compParty populates, myParty changes to match it.

edit: as requested my _partyService GetParty Class.

```
public async Task<List<CreatureBase>> GetParty(ulong playerID)
        {
            try
            {
                List<CreatureBase> party = new List<CreatureBase>();

                Dictionary<ulong, string> partyMembers = new Dictionary<ulong, string>();
                partyMembers.Add(0, "Testy");

                foreach (var pM in partyMembers)
                {
                    var cList = await _creatureService.GetCreatureList();
                    var c = cList.Where(x => x.Key == pM.Value).FirstOrDefault();

                    var newCreature = await _creatureService.GetCreatureStats(playerID, c.Value);

                    party.Add(newCreature);
                }

                return party;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

as i said previously, this does return the 2 different results expected, but myParty gets changed when this returns the second result to compParty

Comment: Can you include your _partyService Class, showing the GetParty() method and overload that are being called?

Comment: @MontanaMan i have added the code, however like i said, in debugging i can see its performing as expected, but its on the second return that the first variable gets overridden

Comment: Is the first `myParty` used later in the function? The compiler may have optimized the code so `myParty` and `compParty` share the same storage since their lifetimes don't overlap.

Comment: @RaymondChen no, the error literally occurs as soon as compParty is populated.  i put an empty line after that call and did a breakpoint, they do not match before compParty is populated, and after it populates myParty changes to match it

Comment: If `myParty` is not used, then the compiler is going to say "Hey look, free memory!" and have `myParty` and `compParty` share the same memory. Add some uage of `myParty` later in the function to prevent the memory from being reused.

Comment: @RaymondChen i use myParty immediately after these calls.

Comment: Okay, just checking. There wasn't enough information in the question to know for sure whether optimizations were kicking in.